# Unable to customize ActionBar Tabs for API-23

Tags: android, xml, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-styles

I'm working on a application in which I am having Tab Bars. I am assigning a custom theme to my tabs using styles.xml present in values-v23 folder. But the thing is that I am not able to achieve my custom theme every time I'm launching the application. I can't understand where is the problem. I am sharing my style.xml file here to make you understand this better.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->

    </style>

    <style name="AppThemeWhite" parent="AppBaseTheme">
            <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
            <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/BlackEditText</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs_TextColor</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabs</item>
            <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTabBar</item>
        </style>

        <!-- action bar tab styles -->
        <style name="CustomActionBarTabs_TextColor" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
            <item name="android:textColor">#666666</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
            <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
        </style>
```

Here I'm trying to change the text color of Tab titles by using the @style/CustomActionBarTabs_TextColor property but nothing is happening. Can someone please help to solve this one. 
Any help would be appreciable.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can apply following style to your tab layout

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/indicatorcolor</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">4dp</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/seltextcolor</item>
</style>

<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="textAllCaps">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I just want to change its text color but after adding parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout" and parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab", it's just showing me error.

Comment: add latest design and appcompat libraries.
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'

Comment: I am using this one - com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1

Comment: Can't I achieve this with my implementation?